# Gnome terminal requires root to open?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

In Dash Home of 12.04, I searched for "terminal", and it came up with "root terminal". To open it, I have to provide the password for root.  It is actually gnome terminal. I wonder if the gnome terminal can be accessed without requiring root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start a user terminal.

Alternately, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-terminal` and press enter.

Comment: Thanks! In what case to press the keys? Under the desktop, it doesn't bring out anything.

Comment: Are you logged in as root somehow? And are you using Unity 2D/3D? Generally any case, anywhere, that shortcut brings up a new gnome-terminal.

Comment: I am logged in as "Tim" which is the administrator. I don't know what is Unity 2D/3D, and how can I find it out?

Comment: Can you press `Alt+F2`, enter `gnome-terminal` and press enter? What happens?

Comment: That will bring out a terminal without requiring root. (1) I wonder why I searched in Dash Home, I could only find "root terminal"? Can I add the gnome terminal to some place easier to find? (2) what does Alt+F2 bring out? It looks like Dash Home, but in Dash Home, I cannot find gnome-terminal.

Comment: (2): Alt+F2 is like the "Run..." option in Windows; you can directly type a command (for a graphical application), and it will execute it.
(1): Can you post a screenshot of what you get when you search for "terminal" in the Dash? This is a weird problem. Perhaps consider one of the many gnome-terminal replacements which should show up in Dash just fine: `xfce4-terminal`, or my personal favorite, `sakura`.

Comment: @lzx: (1) I searched for "gnome-terminal" in Dash Home under installed software (the first tab). It says "Sorry. There is nothing that match your search." I don't know how to screenshot, since the window for Dash Home disappear if I click the screen shot application's window to take a shot.